# Guarantee Search Engines Don't Scrape One Subdir of Site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

On a Linux, Apache, PHP site, **I need to make certain that a subdirectory /cms, on my website is not crawlable by the search engines**.

See, in the root of the site, I have installed a product catalog called Pinnacle Cart. They wanted a News page that pulls content from a CMS. I brought WordPress online in a subdirectory called /cms, created some posts, and then used the following code to bring that into my Pinnacle Cart theme:

```
<?php require_once('../../../cms/wp-blog-header.php'); ?>
<?php $i = 1; $MAX_ARTICLES_TO_SHOW = 5; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_id(); ?>">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry -->
        <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
        <small><?php the_time('F j, Y') ?></small>
    </div><!-- #post-... -->
<?php ++$i; if ($i > $MAX_ARTICLES_TO_SHOW) { break; } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Note that some of the images used in the posts will pull from /cms, and I want those to load okay, but I don't want Google or any search engine to follow anything under /cms.

Note also in WordPress in /cms, I checked off the setting "Do not let sites like Google, Technorati, etc. index this site."

I'm thinking I'll need to either adjust the default theme for the WordPress under /cms/wp-content/themes, or put some sort of .htaccess setting in the /cms or / (root) folder of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your robots.txt file.

```
Disallow: /cms/
```

Reads more about it at http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Search engines and scrapers can always ignore this though (Most large search engines will follow the rules). You could check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` too, but this can be faked. There is no 100% way of stopping scrapers.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the robots.txt file.  That's a file read by search engines before crawling your site.  In that file, you can instruct them to completely ignore certain directories.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use robots.txt 
It's a file that you place in your root directory that all robots read before crawling your site. In this file you can specify directories that you don't want to be crawled. A few links to get you started 
http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html http://codex.wordpress.org/Search_Engine_Optimization_for_WordPress#Robots.txt_Optimization

Answer (score 0):

robots.txt is one option, as stated in the other answers here.

```
Disallow: /cms/
```

The main disadvantage of a robots.txt file is that they can be ignored, or merely overlooked depending on the robot.

- http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156449
- http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

You also have the option of password protecting the directory which will prevent search engines indexing the page (Example articles from [Google](http://www.google.com/support/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72365) and [Bing](http://www.bing.com/community/webmaster/f/12252/t/646805.aspx)). Depending on your server environment you could also disallow access to the CMS folder using .htaccess and .htpasswd. This method allows users to visit the Wordpress installation, but not bots/unauthenticated users.

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html#auth

Another option would be to set up headers 404 or 301s for that particular directory, again using `.htaccess`. This would obviously stop users visiting it too so if you wanted to block it only for bots you could whitelist certain IPs or user-agent strings to allow real users to see the page and bots to receive a 404 header which would prevent indexing the page.